# DBpedia get all cities in the world - missing a few

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I use this sparql query to get as much cities as possible:

```
select * where {
    ?city rdf:type dbo:PopulatedPlace
}
```

However, some expected ones are missing e.g.

http://dbpedia.org/resource/Heidelberg
(neither that nor one of its wikiRedirects)

which is of a dbo:PopulatedPlace as this query returns true (in JSON):

```
ask {
    :Heidelberg a dbo:PopulatedPlace
}
```

I need that list to be exhaustiv because later I will add constraints based on user input.

I use http://dbpedia.org/snorql/ to test the queries.

Any help is appreciated.

UPDATE:
One of the Devs told me the public endpoint is limited ( about 1K ).
I'll come up with a paginated solution and see if it contains the 'outlier'.

UPDATE2:
The outlier is definitly in the resultset of rdf:type dbo:Town.
Using dbo:PopulatedPlace yields too many results to check per hand, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The public endpoint limits results to about 1K. Pagination or use of a smaller subclass of dbo:PopulatedPlace yields the result.